# Read .json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, file, javascript-objects

I am looking for a javscript code that will load/read .json file (e.g. myData.json)
from my local machine (e.g. some folder in C drive or downloads folder in my laptop) on click on a button on webpage

Comment: javascript in browser or are you using node.js?

Comment: javascript in browser

Answer (score 0):

Using node.js, you can simply require the file:

```
var package = require('./package.json');
```

which would load your npm package.json file, (relative path permitting)

To load a JSON file into your browser, into a website, is a little more tricky as you will need to have a server running on the machine that you want to load the files from.

Or you could build in a file upload feature to your website, that would allow you to upload a local file and your JS could parse it

Comment: Sorry for not a asking question clearly. There will be a button on webpage and on click on this button i need to read file